# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array exception

Tags: c#, exception, decode, encode

i have exception when i run this code ,, what is wrong

```
   var encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
   System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();
   byte[] todecodeByte = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedMsg);
   int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecodeByte, 0, todecodeByte.Length);
   var decodedChar = new char[charCount];
   utf8Decode.GetChars(todecodeByte, 0, todecodeByte.Length, decodedChar, 0);
   var message = new String(decodedChar);
```

exception occurs in this line

```
byte[] todecodeByte = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedMsg);
```

Comment: Going to need some more information.  What is the contents of `encodedMsg`? where does the exception occur?  Etc ...

Comment: Does the encoded message contain numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base64 encoding encodes 6 bits per character.  So the length of the string, multiplied by 6, must be divisible by 8.  If it is not then it doesn't have enough bits to fill every byte and you'll get this exception.

So good odds that *encodedMsg* just isn't a properly encoded base64 string.  You can append some = characters to bypass the exception and see if anything recognizable pops out.  The = character is the padding character for base64:

```
while ((encodedMsg.Length * 6) % 8 != 0) encodedMsg += "=";
// etc...
```